# floating point negative variable not setting to zero when assigned javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, variable-assignment

I have created a button that should decrease the value in a given text field by units of 0.5, except when the field is empty or is 0. ie it should stay 0 on further clicks after it reaches 0 instead of going into negative values. But it still continues to go into negative values.
The function for this button is

```
function minusButton(n)
{
    var fieldname = "auc_dec"+n;
    //used to get id tag for element, is working fine in a separate plus button

    var entry = document.getElementById(fieldname).value;
    if(entry!='')
    {   
        entry = Number(entry) - 0.5;
        document.getElementById(fieldname).value = entry;
    }
    else if(Number(entry)<0)
    {
        entry = "0";
        document.getElementById(fieldname).value = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: try saying `else if(Number(entry)<=0)` .

Comment: @Mritunjay not working, man

Comment: add a fiddle, that will be better.

Comment: I have added an answer what I tried, i din't had your HTML but trying to create function for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because you've checked that if entry is not `''` decrease it. So it is going to first `if` and `entry` getting decreased.

I got this working for me change your function accordingly

HTML:-

```
<input type="text" id="auto"/>
<button onclick="minusButton()">minusButton</button>
```

Javascript

```
function minusButton(){
  var entry = document.getElementById('auto').value;
  if(entry=='' || Number(entry)<=0)
  {
      entry = "0";
      document.getElementById('auto').value = "0";   
      return;
  }
  entry = Number(entry) - 0.5;
  document.getElementById('auto').value = entry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the if ... else statement to:

```
var entry =
document.getElementById(fieldname).value;

if (Number(entry) <= 0) {
entry = Number (entry);
document.getElementById(fieldname).value = entry;
} else  {
entry = Number (entry) - 1.5;
document.getElementById(fieldname).value = entry;
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work, but its worth a try...